# Unable to enter password in terminal

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, password, reboot

Ubuntu is not working correctly. Keyboard up and down arrow behave wrong. In terminal i am giving correct password but it says sorry try again. And if i press down arrow in keyboard it's makes unusual sounds.

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `declare -p SUDO_ASKPASS`